# should value must be quoted in JSON along with key

Tags: java, android, json

i have data
like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Student Statement Report",
    "data": {
        "data": [{
            "id": "45",
            "transaction_no": "45",
            "transaction_date": "2017-05-25",
            "transaction_type": "invoice",
            "transaction_amount": "1010.00",
            "related_invoice_id": "45",
            "balance_amount": "1010.00",
            "related_user_id": "436",
            "related_user_group": "student",
            "description": "",
            "created_by": "Principal",
            "updated_by": "Principal",
            "created_at": "2017-05-25 11:57:39",
            "updated_at": "2017-05-25 11:57:39"
        }],
        "opening_balance": 0,
        "dates": ["2017-05-22 00:00:00", "2017-05-28 23:59:59"]
    }
}


                  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

and i am geeting Json expection error from here
                          String openingBalance = jsonObject.getString("opening_balance");

"opening_balance": 0, 
so, my biggest question is should that zero (value) should be quoted or not?

Comment: post your code where your getting error

Comment: what's Your type of opening_balance?

Comment: No, it's a numerical value, it should not be quoted. Look closer. Something else is wrong.

Comment: post your response json

Comment: jsonObject.getInt("opening_balance"); try this

Comment: and make openingBalance int or type cast to string as you want to use it

Comment: Please learn some json basics... opening_balance is not at root level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse it like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");//Get Data object
 int openingBalance = data.getInt("opening_balance");//Get opening balance
```

Comment: @kenji your selected answer is wrong. Nilesh Rathod answer is write because of data object inside opening_balance object.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the number as an **Integer** then quotation is not necessary. But if your read it as a **String** then you have to put quotation.

To read as an **Integer** you can use `getInt("json_key")`
& for **String** `getString("json_key")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");//Get Data object
int openingBalance = data.getInt("opening_balance");//Get opening balance
```